# Create one object and update another in one request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails application, I would like to do some action after a user is signed in. For example:

- A user is browsing the site. He has *not* logged in.
- The user creates a new object on the site. Since the user is not logged in, the object is publicly visible.
- The user now wants to make the object private. He clicks the "make private" button.
- Since he is not logged in, the site does not know who to associate the private object with. It redirects him to the login form.
- The user logs into his account. This uses a standard RESTful POST request to log him in. Then -- and this is the part I need help with -- it also updates the object to make it private. It then redirects him back to the (now private) object view.

I'm new to Rails, but my understanding is that I can't send a PUT request from the login controller to the other object controller, since redirects don't allow you to POST data.

I suppose I could also put some GET variables in the login path (i.e. http://example.com/login?ref=123&action=make_private) which the login controller could interpret as "make object with ID 123 private." The login controller could check for the existence of these params whenever a new login is created, and handle the updating of that object itself. But it seems like there must be a better way than to replicate the update action from the object's controller into the login controller.

One last option I've thought of is changing the workflow so that instead of seeing a "make private" button, users just see a "login to make updates" button, but it is less convenient to separate these actions than to make them possible with one click, so I would prefer to do this only as a last resort.

Am I overlooking something? What is the correct way to do something like this (if there *is* a correct way)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you're asking so I'll try stepping you through it.

At the point the user clicks "make private" there is an object that has already been created, correct? Assuming so then simply pass that object id along with the "make private" command when the not logged in user is redirected to the login page. This means you should have a param list with something like the following: `object_id => "1", method => "make_private"`

Now you have a choice, you can either update the object within the check for valid login method you should already have by doing this:

```
if params[:object_id] && params[:method] == "make_private"
  #make object private
  redirect_to objects_path(params[:object_id])
else 
  #normal login redirect
end
```

or you can redirect in your login confirm method to the object's update method and from their redirect to the object's view page with something like the following:

```
def login_validation
  #normal login checking
  if params[:object_id] && params[:method] == "make_private"
    redirect_to object_path(params[:object_id])
  else
    #redirect to normal after login page
  end
end
```

then in your update you'll want:

```
def update
  #normal update stuff   
  redirect_to objects_path(params[:object_id])
end
```

Obviously you'll need something that will detect the "make private" command in your update method but that shouldn't be too difficult. If you need help on that just comment here and I'll add the instructions for that as well.

Update:
If you really wanted to be fancy you could pass the redirect path itself into the login function and then just redirect to whatever the login path was provided.

For example your make private button could look like this

`<%= button_to "Make Private", object_path(:id=>object_id) %>`

Then it would attempt to update, realize it had no logged in user, and redirect to login page like so:

```
def update
  if user_logged_in?
    #do normal update stuff
  else
    redirect_to login_path(:redirect_path => object_path(params[:id])
end
```

Then they'd fill out their normal information and when they clicked confirm it would have an additional parameter like so:

`<%= button_to "Confirm", login_validation_path(<normal login params>,params[:redirect_path]) %>`

Then inside your login_validation you'd do your normal validations and then redirect to whatever path you were given.

```
def login_validation
  #normal login stuffs
  if params[:redirect_path]
    redirect_to params[:redirect_path]
  else
    #normal redirect
end
```

That way your login could handle being called from multiple varying locations and correctly redirect to wherever you wanted it to.

Comment: Thanks. To clarify, my understanding is that to route to an update action you need to send a PUT request, which I didn't think you could do via redirect_to. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @user108338 Yup. You can use PUT requests through redirect_to no problem. You just have to make sure whatever receives the PUT either renders or redirects_to somewhere else that has a valid view attached since most updates won't have an attached ERB file.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by *simply updating your object inside the action where you are creating your user*, but you have to **send your objects id to your create action** *so that you could update that object* and make it private.

```
def create
  @user = User.new user_params
  if @user.save
    @object = Object.find(params[:object_id])
    @object.update_attributes(:private => true)
  else
    render new
  end
end
```

You can also use Active records [**`after_create callback`**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :update_object

  def update_object
    #your logic to update object
  end
end
```

**Update:**

If you want to update your object after a user logs in then you can do:

a. create your route to send **a post request** *so that you can send your objects id*:

```
post '/object/:id' => "your_controller#update_object", as: 'update_object'
```

b. Make your **link to update that object**:

```
<%= link_to "object", update_object_path(@object.id), method: :post %>
```

c. In your *method update your object:*

```
def update_object
  @object = Object.find(params[:id])
  @object.update_attributes(:private => true)
  redirect_to your_path, notice: "object made private"
end
```

If you are *using devise for authentication then you can get your user by* `current_user` and if you have your custom authentication then *you can make a method to find your current user*

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   def current_user
     @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
   end
 end
```

Comment: I don't think a user is being created.

Comment: @DickieBoy if you look at his title `Create one object and update another in one request`

Comment: @DickieBoy will update my answer to update object once user log in.

Comment: Right, sorry, the object being created is the login object (an object representing the user's logged in session).

Comment: @user108338 updated my answer to update your object once a user logs in

Comment: @user108338 it's true that rails uses `put` request to update a `resource` but in your case you want to update your object by a link you are not using a form and you can do it by a `post` request